# Try Catch fails on stock Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I run this code from within an iframe to determine if I have top DOM level access:

```
canAccessParentDOM:function(){
    try {
        window.top.document;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This works as expected on all desktop browsers, including mobile Chrome. However, this fails on the stock Android browser running on my Galaxy S3. When I open the javascript console for the browser, the DOM exception in the try block is not being caught.

Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: is there an error at all?

Comment: just the DOM  error that's not being caught.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is responding to this, I'm going to assume I'm doing it the wrong way and close it. I found another way to determine top DOM level access anyway.